# How to decode a JSON with unknown keys at the top-level?

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I would like to know how I can decode this JSON:

```json
{
    "unknown_key1": {
        "info": "Info text",
        "text": "More text"
    },
    "unknown_key2": {
        "info": "Info text",
        "text": "More text"
    },
    ...
}
```

I have started writing something like this:

```
JSONDecode().decode(Test.self, from: data)
```

**Test**

```
struct Test: Decodable {
    let content: [String: Content]
}

struct Content: Decodable {
    let info: String
    let text: String
}
```

This doesn't work and I have no idea of what to do.

(I want to emphasize on the fact that I have set `unknown_key1` and `unknown_key2` as examples but these keys can be absolutely anything else.)

Comment: There is no "content" key in your JSON. What does say the thrown error?

Comment: This is quite different from the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON structure you posted is a Dictionary `[String:Content]`.

Decoding would look like:

```
try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Content].self, from: data)
```

there is no top level element.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that I could use a dictionary in JSONDecoder's decode().